# GetResponse API tag users depening on the visited page

Tags: php, yii, getresponse

I have integrate this API: https://github.com/GetResponse/getresponse-api-php into a Yii application, as a component.

I am having some trouble understanding something about this API so my question is, can I tags my users depending on what page they visited ?

Comment: Hi @chandlerbing , On this matter I have't tried anything, I have no idea where to start. What I've done so far is I attached a subscriebe checkbox. And if the user checks it, I add that user to getResponse. I'll leave a comment with that code

Comment: Do I get it right that you want to assign custom fields to subscribers depending on the page on which they are subscribing?
If you actually meant tags, which are a different entity inside GetResponse, then you'd need to firstly add a subscriber, then get its id by searching by email and assign a tag using that id. Assigning custom fields seems to be more optimal to me.

Comment: No more need, I've resolved all the issues on my own.

Answer (score 0):

This is the piece of code where I add the user to getresponse.

```
$wants_subscription = $_POST['getresponse_subscription'];
            if( $wants_subscription == 1 ){
                if( class_exists('GetResponse') ){
                    $get_response = new GetResponse('my-api-key');
                    $get_response->enterprise_domain = 'my-domain';
                    $get_response->api_url = 'https://api3.getresponse360.com/v3';

                    // Add contact
                    $add_contact = $get_response->addContact(array(
                        'name' => $_POST['name'],
                        'email' => $_POST['email'],
                        'daysofCycle' => 0,
                        'campaign' => array('campaignId' => 'x')

                    ));
```